# Break a while loop from another script

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, gpio

I'm trying to break a while loop from a function call blink. 
blink is from the script **control.py**. 
This is run from the script **main.py**. 
My aim is to call blink function and to stop blink when the function off is called.

I have tried calling with a *While x = "0"* and calling X on the off function

**Control.py**

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser 
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
from time import sleep as sleep
import xmlrpclib 

#setup settings
parser = SafeConfigParser() 
parser.read('/home/pi/ns/led.conf') # get GPIO Pin & Run time settings
proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8000/") #Set host for LCD Screen


GPIO_PIN = int(parser.get('settings', 'GPIO_PIN'))#Set GPIO pin
run = float(parser.get('settings', 'run_time'))#set run time

def gpio():
 return GPIO_PIN 
int(parser.get('settings', 'GPIO_PIN'))#Set

def setup_gpio():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setup(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
def on():
    try:
        proxy.normal()
        GPIO.output(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
        proxy.stat_ok()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        GPIO.cleanup()
        notify(e)
def off():
    try:
        proxy.normal()
        GPIO.output(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
        proxy.stat_ok()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        GPIO.cleanup()
        notify(e)
def blink():
    try:
        proxy.normal()
        while true:
         GPIO.output(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
         sleep(run)
         GPIO.output(GPIO_PIN, GPIO.LOW)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        GPIO.cleanup()
        notify(e)
try:
 server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8001), allow_none=True)
 print "Control Listening on port 8001..."
 proxy.control_on() 
 server.register_function(on) 
 server.register_function(off) 
 server.register_function(blink) 
 server.serve_forever()
except Exception as error:
    print error
    proxy.control_off()
```

**main.py**

```
import xmlrpclib 
control = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8001/")
while True:
    cont = raw_input("Please select (O)n, (B)link, or O(F)F :")  
    if cont == "O":
     control.on() # LED ON
    elif cont == "F":
     control.off() # LED OFF
    elif cont == "B":
     control.blink() # LED BLINK
    else:
     print "please try again"
```

Comment: for the person who suggested edit. You failed to fix the command.on() to control.on()  so next time you want to edit code please edit the whole thing properly as you would have caused errors and complaints

Comment: What happens if you command blink twice? Does the LED blink rwice as fast?

Comment: Sure why not hell it runs 4x as fast... Magic right?  It doesn't return to raw_input as it stuck in a loop..  Fancy that.. A